# Hover not working in FireFox in device mode

Tags: css, angular, firefox, hover

I have an image and when you hover over it some text appears. This works in both Chrome and FireFox on the desktop. But in FireFox when I select a device like the iPhone in the responsive design mode, suddenly the hover doesn't work anymore but it is fine in Chrome when I test on the same device.

```
.campaigns-container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Is there something I need to add for devices?

```
<mat-card class="campaigns-container">
    <img
        class="campaign-image"
        mat-card-image
        src="{{ campaignImageSource }}"
    />
    <div
        class="overlay overlay-fade">
        <div class="fx-align-space-evenly-center">
            <div class="campaign-question m-6 fx-flex-50">
                <h2 class="mat-caption">
                    {{ informationStrings['question'] }}
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: You can’t hover on a touch device. Do you have the touch option enabled in FireFox but not in Chrome?

Comment: @DanMullin yes on the device I do have to click for the text to show, but I haven't added any extra code for that and it works when I click on Chrome, but not in FireFox

Answer (score 3):

By default, when you select iPhone, Firefox will simulate touch mode in which `:hover` does not work.

You can turn it off with the right-most button on the toolbar.

[image: Firefox responsive toolbar screenshot]

Comment: Yes I can turn it off and hover works again but I need to test the touch on devices to. The touch works in Chrome (I haven't added anything to make touch work) but not in FireFox. Is there something extra I need to add for touch on FireFox?

Comment: This was actually driving me crazy. It makes sense as default when you think about it but man what a face palm, I wasted a lot of time troubleshooting why my `:hover` wasn't working lol